# AutoRun/AutoPlay in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

It's widely known and accepted by most tech-savvy people, especially those with an affinity for security, that AutoRun/AutoPlay should be disabled due to a number of attack vectors that it opens up. However, Windows 8 appears to still have these features enabled by default.

Is there something about Windows 8's handling of AutoRun/AutoPlay that makes this more secure than earlier versions? Or should we still be locking this setting down?

Comment: For USB, all AutoRun does is open a window asking you what you want to do with the drive... surely that's not too much of a security risk?

Comment: @KnightOfNi If it's taking any information from autorun.ini or other data sources on the drive to present options to the user (like logos, device name, etc.) there still remains a risk that flaws in handling such data can lead to improper presentation of options or even code execution. This was at the heart of some AutoRun/AutoPlay vulnerabilities in the past, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Got it... so AutoPlay isn't a vulnerability so much as an attack vector.

Comment: @KnightOfNi Yeah. That's why I used "attack vector" in my OP. ;-)