# Is it recommended to disable Autoplay in Windows 11 from a security perspective?

Tags: windows-11

Historically, Autorun [has been](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83391/autorun-autoplay-in-windows-8) an attack vector, but a lot has changed since then, Windows Security (Defender) and lots of improvements to everything. so now I'm wondering, on latest Windows 11 build, is it safe to leave Autoplay on (which is the default) and be sure it won't be used as attack vector when plugging in USB, memory cards etc. ?

p.s [it's Not autorun](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-configure-autoplay-windows-10).

Comment: AFAIK Autorun for writeable media has been removed from Windows. Only for read-only media like CDs it is still possible to have Autorun.

Comment: Thanks, so it's no longer a recommended security practice to disable Autoplay in Windows 11? because Autorun doesn't exist on Windows 11, and Autoplay feature in settings is only "a feature that allows you to decide a default action when connecting a USB drive, memory card, and other kind of media or device to your computer." https://www.windowscentral.com/how-configure-autoplay-windows-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it safe to remove all seatbelts when there are airbags in the car? No.

Defence happens in layers. No single layer is effective. So, no, it is not recommended to turn on Autorun. All security frameworks insist that it remain off.

USB ***will*** be used as an attack vector. It is ***currently and actively*** used as an attack vector (see [Raspberry Robin](https://thehackernews.com/2022/12/raspberry-robin-worm-strikes-again.html)). Having a defense to a vector does not mean that the attack vector won't be used. With a defence, you just hope the attack will fail. Which is why you use layers of defences.

Comment: it's my bad, I edited my question, the question I linked confused me and i mixed up autoplay with autorun. my question is only about autoplay in Windows 11, there is no mention of autorun that i've seen and I don't know if it even exists. you can correct me if i'm wrong or point me to an official documentation. and from what I've read, and Autoplay feature in settings is only "a feature that allows you to decide a default action when connecting a USB drive, memory card, and other kind of media or device to your computer."  https://www.windowscentral.com/how-configure-autoplay-windows-10

Comment: Yes, I understand. Autoplay and autorun are the same thing. My answer is the same for both.

Answer (score 0):

Auto execution or parsing of data from an OS is always susceptible to exploitation.

In principle, defense mechanisms base their behaviour on known attacks, so they are inadequate against new types of attacks (e.g. zero-day exploits, new behaviours etc).

I don't see any point in enabling autorun; it saves you, what? A couple of mouse clicks? And opens the door to a system compromise. A lot of risk for such a small value gained, in my opinion.

[autoplay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoPlay) and [autorun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun) are closely related; autoplay "[...] [automatically launches applications to play or display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144210(v=vs.85)) [...]" media files (e.g. videos, music or pictures). Which means that a specially crafted media file can exploit your media viewer and compromise your system.